# Cómo eliminar duplicados de 2 arrays con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, eliminar-duplicados

¿Cómo puedo eliminar un objeto que existe en ambos arrays? Ejemplo:
ARRAY 1

```
const personas = [
 { id: 2, nombre: 'Edu', edad: 35, },
 { id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34, }
];
```

ARRAY 2

```
const personas2 = [
 { id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34, }
];
```

RESULTADO ESPERADO

> [{ id: 2, nombre: 'Edu', edad: 35 }]

He intentado con esto:

```
const prueba = ['alvaro', 'rocio', 'maricarmen'];
const prueba2 = ['alvaro', 'rocio'];
let nuevo_arraglo = prueba.filter(n => prueba2.indexOf(n) == -1);
```

y funciona en un array de string o de números pero de objetos no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo parecido a la solución de @HeytalePazguato, usando el método [**`every()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const personas = [
  { id: 2, nombre: 'Edu', edad: 35 },
  { id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34 },
];
const personas2 = [{ id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34 }];

const filtrado = personas.filter((el) => {
  return !personas2.every((f) => f.id === el.id && f.nombre === el.nombre && f.edad === el.edad);
});

console.log(filtrado);
```

O también con [**`reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const personas = [
  { id: 2, nombre: 'Edu', edad: 35 },
  { id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34 },
];
const personas2 = [{ id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34 }];

const filtrado = personas.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!personas2.some((f) => f.id === el.id && f.nombre === el.nombre && f.edad === el.edad)) {
    acc.push(el);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filtrado);
```

Answer (score 2):

Buen día,

Tal vez no es la forma más elegante o más corta de hacerlo pero se me ocurre utilizar `filter` en conjunto con [`some`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp):

```js
const personas = [
 { id: 2, nombre: 'Edu', edad: 35, },
 { id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34, }
];
const personas2 = [
 { id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34, }
];

const filtrado = personas.filter((el) => {
  return personas2.some((f) => {
    if (f.id === el.id && f.nombre === el.nombre && f.edad === el.edad) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
  });
});

console.log(filtrado);
```

Comment: me funciono era lo que buscaba, muchas gracias

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!

Comment: aplicándolo a mi proyecto solo elimina un objeto pero si el array personas2 tiene más de un objeto no lo hace bien, la mejor forma es hacerlo con un reduce como la respuesta de Cris223511.dev

Answer (score 1):

Podes crear una función propia, equivalente a la función Array.includes() pero para arrays de objetos, y luego usar reduce() para obtener los no repetidos:

```js
let personas = [
  { id: 2, nombre: 'Edu', edad: 35 },
  { id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34 },
  { id: 4, nombre: 'Micaela', edad: 31 },
  { id: 7, nombre: 'Juan', edad: 21 },
  { id: 7, nombre: 'Ricardo', edad: 47 }
];

 let personas2 = [
  { id: 5, nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 34 },
  { id: 7, nombre: 'Juan', edad: 21 },
  { id: 2, nombre: 'Edu', edad: 35 },
];

function includesObj(arr,myobj) { // recibe un array y un objeto. Determina si dicho objeto existe en el array
  for(const obj of arr)
    if(obj.id == myobj.id && obj.nombre == myobj.nombre && obj.edad == myobj.edad) return true
  return false
}

personas = personas.reduce((acc, elem) => { // usando un reduce:
  if(!includesObj(personas2,elem)) acc.push(elem) // usamos la funcion para agregar elementos no repetidos al acumulador
  return acc;
},[])

console.log(personas)
```

Es una alternativa. Saludos.